# How can I see the mouse pointer as it performs actions in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I'm using Selenium Java WebDriver to automate UI tests. It works fine but it doesn't show the mouse pointer as it performs actions like clicking on a button. How can I make the mouse pointer visible as it moves on the page and clicks on a button?

Comment: Not sure but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867776/visualize-show-mouse-cursor-position-in-selenium-2-tests-for-example-phpunit/35867777#35867777) may help!

Comment: @CoderCroc the answer you are referring to creates a mouse and focuses on it (if I understand correctly). Selenium WebDriver has the `Actions` module that does this perfectly! see my answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can highlight the elements that you are interacting with usings JS.

```
    String jsSyyle = "'3px solid red'";
    WebElement element; 
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border=" + jsSyyle, element);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is with `Actions` see [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html).

For example:

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement myElement = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("the/xpath/to/element"));
action.moveToElement(myElement).click().build().perform();
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems that using the Actions class should do it, but so far it isn't. I tried using both Firefox and Chrome webdrivers to no avail. Mouse doesn't move. I'll investigate more.

Comment: Do you actually see the mouse pointer moving inside the browser window from one place to another using the Actions class, or do you just see the effect? What version of selenium-server jar are you using? I'm using `3.141.59`, on Mac, and Chrome latest `71.0.3578.98`.

Comment: I do this on windows... but I don't think that is the problem... try this: add an element without clicking on it just move to it... maybe it's just too fast...

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't keep track of the cursor because that's the job of the operating system.

Thanks to this answer :[Show mouse cursor position in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669454/5232323) you can draw a cursor.

```
# python
enable_cursor = """
        function enableCursor() {
          var seleniumFollowerImg = document.createElement("img");
          seleniumFollowerImg.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,'
            + 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAQAAACGG/bgAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAJcEhZcwAA'
            + 'HsYAAB7GAZEt8iwAAAAHdElNRQfgAwgMIwdxU/i7AAABZklEQVQ4y43TsU4UURSH8W+XmYwkS2I0'
            + '9CRKpKGhsvIJjG9giQmliHFZlkUIGnEF7KTiCagpsYHWhoTQaiUUxLixYZb5KAAZZhbunu7O/PKf'
            + 'e+fcA+/pqwb4DuximEqXhT4iI8dMpBWEsWsuGYdpZFttiLSSgTvhZ1W/SvfO1CvYdV1kPghV68a3'
            + '0zzUWZH5pBqEui7dnqlFmLoq0gxC1XfGZdoLal2kea8ahLoqKXNAJQBT2yJzwUTVt0bS6ANqy1ga'
            + 'VCEq/oVTtjji4hQVhhnlYBH4WIJV9vlkXLm+10R8oJb79Jl1j9UdazJRGpkrmNkSF9SOz2T71s7M'
            + 'SIfD2lmmfjGSRz3hK8l4w1P+bah/HJLN0sys2JSMZQB+jKo6KSc8vLlLn5ikzF4268Wg2+pPOWW6'
            + 'ONcpr3PrXy9VfS473M/D7H+TLmrqsXtOGctvxvMv2oVNP+Av0uHbzbxyJaywyUjx8TlnPY2YxqkD'
            + 'dAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
          seleniumFollowerImg.setAttribute('id', 'selenium_mouse_follower');
          seleniumFollowerImg.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; z-index: 99999999999; pointer-events: none; left:0; top:0');
          document.body.appendChild(seleniumFollowerImg);
          document.onmousemove = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("selenium_mouse_follower").style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
            document.getElementById("selenium_mouse_follower").style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
          };
        };

        enableCursor();
"""

driver.execute_script(enable_cursor)
```