# Simulate mouse movement with Capybara

Tags: capybara

I would like to demonstrate onscreen mouse movements when running Capybara tests. I have had a request to make the mouse movements a user would make visible, in addition to running through data points etc. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly supported in any Capybara drivers I know of, however you can fake the mouse pointer with some JS as shown at [Visualize / Show mouse cursor position in selenium 2 tests (for example PHPUnit Webdriver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867776/visualize-show-mouse-cursor-position-in-selenium-2-tests-for-example-phpunit/35867777#35867777)

Basically it boils down to creating an image and then moving its location every time a `mousemove` event occurs

```
// Create mouse following image.
var seleniumFollowerImg = document.createElement("img");

// Set image properties.
seleniumFollowerImg.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,'
    + 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAQAAACGG/bgAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAJcEhZcwAA'
    + 'HsYAAB7GAZEt8iwAAAAHdElNRQfgAwgMIwdxU/i7AAABZklEQVQ4y43TsU4UURSH8W+XmYwkS2I0'
    + '9CRKpKGhsvIJjG9giQmliHFZlkUIGnEF7KTiCagpsYHWhoTQaiUUxLixYZb5KAAZZhbunu7O/PKf'
    + 'e+fcA+/pqwb4DuximEqXhT4iI8dMpBWEsWsuGYdpZFttiLSSgTvhZ1W/SvfO1CvYdV1kPghV68a3'
    + '0zzUWZH5pBqEui7dnqlFmLoq0gxC1XfGZdoLal2kea8ahLoqKXNAJQBT2yJzwUTVt0bS6ANqy1ga'
    + 'VCEq/oVTtjji4hQVhhnlYBH4WIJV9vlkXLm+10R8oJb79Jl1j9UdazJRGpkrmNkSF9SOz2T71s7M'
    + 'SIfD2lmmfjGSRz3hK8l4w1P+bah/HJLN0sys2JSMZQB+jKo6KSc8vLlLn5ikzF4268Wg2+pPOWW6'
    + 'ONcpr3PrXy9VfS473M/D7H+TLmrqsXtOGctvxvMv2oVNP+Av0uHbzbxyJaywyUjx8TlnPY2YxqkD'
    + 'dAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
seleniumFollowerImg.setAttribute('id', 'selenium_mouse_follower');
seleniumFollowerImg.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; z-index: 99999999999; pointer-events: none;');

// Add mouse follower to the web page.
document.body.appendChild(seleniumFollowerImg);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  const mousePointer = document.getElementById('selenium_mouse_follower');
  mousePointer.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  mousePointer.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
});
```

You would then need to make sure that JS gets executed after every page change (visit, click that navigates, etc). There are many ways you do that, with the simplest being either conditionally add the code to your app in test mode or calling it manually with a helper method calling `page.execute_js` whenever you want the mouse position to be shown for the next actions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response @thomas-walpole. Would I be able to use this code with Selenium IDE or would it have to be WebDriver?

Comment: @Incertus  However you add that JS to the page and run it (could be from the Selenium IDE execute script command) it will show the alternative mouse pointer as the test moves the pointer, however the suggestion to use `page.execute_script` from my answer will only work inside your Capybara tests.