# How to animate a mouse cursor in a webdriverio webpage test

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I have a webdriverio test that automates the clicking of different elements in a web app to produce an outcome. I'd like to have a mouse pointer animate movement between each click.

The ultimate goal is to create animated videos illustrating how to use our web app that can easily be updated in code when the web app UI changes (with different IDs/classes/elements in the UI).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505120/22799014), I've added the following to a working webdriverio test:

```
      var mouse = document.createElement('img');
        console.log("test");
        mouse.setAttribute(
            'src',
            'data:image/png;base64,' +
            'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAQAAACGG/bgAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAJcEhZcwAA' +
            'HsYAAB7GAZEt8iwAAAAHdElNRQfgAwgMIwdxU/i7AAABZklEQVQ4y43TsU4UURSH8W+XmYwkS2I0' +
            '9CRKpKGhsvIJjG9giQmliHFZlkUIGnEF7KTiCagpsYHWhoTQaiUUxLixYZb5KAAZZhbunu7O/PKf' +
            'e+fcA+/pqwb4DuximEqXhT4iI8dMpBWEsWsuGYdpZFttiLSSgTvhZ1W/SvfO1CvYdV1kPghV68a3' +
            '0zzUWZH5pBqEui7dnqlFmLoq0gxC1XfGZdoLal2kea8ahLoqKXNAJQBT2yJzwUTVt0bS6ANqy1ga' +
            'VCEq/oVTtjji4hQVhhnlYBH4WIJV9vlkXLm+10R8oJb79Jl1j9UdazJRGpkrmNkSF9SOz2T71s7M' +
            'SIfD2lmmfjGSRz3hK8l4w1P+bah/HJLN0sys2JSMZQB+jKo6KSc8vLlLn5ikzF4268Wg2+pPOWW6' +
            'ONcpr3PrXy9VfS473M/D7H+TLmrqsXtOGctvxvMv2oVNP+Av0uHbzbxyJaywyUjx8TlnPY2YxqkD' +
            'dAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
        );
        mouse.id = 'webdriver-mouse';
        mouse.setAttribute(
            'style',
            'position: absolute; z-index: 999999; pointer-events: none; left:0; top:0'
        );
        console.log(mouse);
        document.appendChild(mouse);
        // console.log(document.getElementById('webdriver-mouse'));
        document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            console.log(event.button)
        });
        document.onclick = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            body.getElementById('webdriver-mouse').style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
            body.getElementById('webdriver-mouse').style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
        };
    });
```

The test passes without an error, but no mouse is being animated.

The `img#webdriver-mouse` is present in the DOM, but not visible to the eye.

It seems the question is: **should webdriverio `click()` functions activate/trigger a `document.onclick` function?**

The test spec file contains:

```
import Studio from '../pageobjects/studio.page'; 
import { Key } from 'webdriverio';

describe('Locking an Element', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {  
        await browser.setWindowSize(1920, 1080);
        await browser.pause(3000);
        await browser.url('/login');
        await(await Studio.usernameField).click();
        await browser.keys('wdio@example.com')
        await(await Studio.passwordInput).click();
        await browser.keys('password');
        await(await Studio.loginSubmit).click();
        await browser.pause(6000);
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        browser.execute('window.localStorage.clear()');     
        browser.deleteAllCookies();
        browser.execute('sessionStorage.clear()');
        browser.refresh();
        browser.pause(3000);
    });
    it('Should lock an element on the canvas', async () => {
        browser.execute(() => {
            var mouse = document.createElement('img');
            mouse.setAttribute(
               'src',
            'data:image/png;base64,' +
            'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAQAAACGG/bgAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAJcEhZcwAA' +
            'HsYAAB7GAZEt8iwAAAAHdElNRQfgAwgMIwdxU/i7AAABZklEQVQ4y43TsU4UURSH8W+XmYwkS2I0' +
            '9CRKpKGhsvIJjG9giQmliHFZlkUIGnEF7KTiCagpsYHWhoTQaiUUxLixYZb5KAAZZhbunu7O/PKf' +
            'e+fcA+/pqwb4DuximEqXhT4iI8dMpBWEsWsuGYdpZFttiLSSgTvhZ1W/SvfO1CvYdV1kPghV68a3' +
            '0zzUWZH5pBqEui7dnqlFmLoq0gxC1XfGZdoLal2kea8ahLoqKXNAJQBT2yJzwUTVt0bS6ANqy1ga' +
            'VCEq/oVTtjji4hQVhhnlYBH4WIJV9vlkXLm+10R8oJb79Jl1j9UdazJRGpkrmNkSF9SOz2T71s7M' +
            'SIfD2lmmfjGSRz3hK8l4w1P+bah/HJLN0sys2JSMZQB+jKo6KSc8vLlLn5ikzF4268Wg2+pPOWW6' +
            'ONcpr3PrXy9VfS473M/D7H+TLmrqsXtOGctvxvMv2oVNP+Av0uHbzbxyJaywyUjx8TlnPY2YxqkD' +
            'dAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
            );
            mouse.id = 'webdriver-mouse';
            mouse.setAttribute(
                'style',
                'position: absolute; z-index: 999999; pointer-events: none; left:0; top:0'
            );
            document.appendChild(mouse);
            document.onclick = function(e) {
                console.log(e);
                body.getElementById('webdriver-mouse').style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
                body.getElementById('webdriver-mouse').style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
            };
        });
        await... //rest of the webdriver test appears here
        ...
```

`wdio.conf.js`:

```
const { join } = require('path')

exports.config = {

specs: [
    './test/specs/**/lock-element.spec.js',
],
maxInstances: 10,
capabilities: [
    {
        maxInstances: 6,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--disable-prompt-on-repost','--window-size=1920,1080'],
            prefs: {
                'profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups' : 2,
                'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications' : 2,
            }
        },
        acceptInsecureCerts: true
     },
],
logLevel: 'error',
bail: 0,
baseUrl: 'https://staging.mandoemedia.com',
waitforTimeout: 10000,
connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
connectionRetryCount: 3,
services:  [['image-comparison',
  {
    baselineFolder: join(process.cwd(), './tests/visualRegressionBaseline/'),
    formatImageName: '{tag}-{logName}',
    screenshotPath: join(process.cwd(), './tests/visualRegressionDiff/'),
    autoSaveBaseline: true,
    blockOutStatusBar: true,
    blockOutToolBar: true,
    clearRuntimeFolder: true,
    disableCSSAnimation: true
  }]
],
framework: 'mocha',
reporters: ['spec'/*['Allure',{
    outputDir:'allure-results',
    disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
    disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
}]*/],
mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 6000000000
},
```

Answer (score 1):

**to answer your question:

no**
WebDriverIO doesn't actually simulate a real user interaction that would trigger the `document.onclick event`.
WebDriverIO interacts directly with the browser's DOM, ingoring any JavaScript event listeners.

working around to this you can use `moveTo`,it not animate the movement but move the cursor to the selected element:

```
const element = await $('#elementId');  
await browser.moveTo(element);
```

WebDriverIO won't cut it, if you need to animate the movement animation of a cursor i suggest using `gsap` or `anime.js`.
here's an example with the latter:

```
anime({
 targets: '#webdriver-mouse',
 left: targetX + 'px',
 top: targetY + 'px',
 duration: 1000, // Duration of the animation in milliseconds
 easing: 'linear'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, `anime.js` looks like it will work. Would appreciate more info about `targetX` & `targetY` - how are they calculated?

Comment: Would I need a function to fire after every webdriverio click() function that calculates `targetX` & `targetY`? (I'm still a JS newbie)

Comment: the coordinates are calculated on the element in the DOM. you can get the position on an element in the web page with the method *getBoundingClientRect* from there you can start playing and discover where that element is in the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Adobe Animate, I highly recommend using that instead. It outputs HTML5 compliant animations that are fully "programmable".

If you don't, then I agree with James, and I would add that animating a cursor or an image using jQuery or Javascript is really not that hard.  You can store the animations in JSON format also with a "steps" array where each step is a JSON object indicating starting position/element and ending position/element, add any actions etc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

Imagine you have a robot (WebDriverIO) that can click on different parts of a website. But making the robot show where it’s clicking can be a bit tricky. We want to record these clicks with a special tool to create a cool video showing how to use the website.

So, the robot clicks on one part of the website, and we want to record the robot’s “hand” moving around (even though it doesn’t really have a hand – it’s like magic). After that, the robot clicks on another part, and we record that too.

Now, we need to use a different tool, like a camera for your computer screen, to capture everything the robot does – the clicking and the magic hand movement. This way, we end up with a video that shows someone using the website step by step.

Think of it like making a tutorial video where you can see every click and movement on the computer screen. The tricky part is that the robot (WebDriverIO) doesn’t know how to show its movements by itself, so we bring in another tool to help us make a cool video.

Here’s a simplified example using WebDriverIO for the clicks, and you can use another tool for recording the mouse movement:

```
const { remote } = require('webdriverio');

(async () => {
  const browser = await remote({
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
    },
  });

  await browser.url('https://example.com');

  // Click on element 1
  await browser.click('#element1');

  // Record mouse movement (use a separate tool for this)
  // ...

  // Click on element 2
  await browser.click('#element2');

  // Record mouse movement
  // ...

  // Continue with other clicks

  await browser.deleteSession();
})();
```

For recording mouse movements, you might use a screen recording tool like OBS Studio, Camtasia, or any other tool that suits your needs. These tools can record both the browser window and the mouse movement, creating an instructional video.

Remember to integrate the WebDriverIO script with the recording tool manually and synchronize the actions as needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it specified how to use webdriverio to make a test, the OP stated I already have a webdriverio test ;-)